# Solve the following composition law equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

$$x\circ y={x+y\over 1+xy}$$$$   G=(-1,1) $$ $$(G,\circ)\text{ stabile part}$$
solve the equation 
$$( \, \underbrace{x\circ x \circ x \circ\cdots\circ x}_{22\text{ times}}\,)=0 $$

Comment: it was proposed by my math tutor .I had 3 points to solve : 1) to show that is stable part 2)to prove that it is associative and has neutral element and the 3rd one was the equation.I had no given function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cute question, but can you say what you've tried or how the question came up?  I've worked with this function before.

If you define $x^\# = \dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$, then you have $(x^\#)^\# = x$ and $(xy)^\# = x^\# \circ y^\#$ and $(x\circ y)^\# = (xy)^\#$.  That means this operation on $(-1,1)^2$ is conjugate to multiplication on $(0,\infty)^2$ (with $-1$ corresponding to $\infty$ and $1$ corresponding to $0$), and you can use that to solve this problem.

It's associative because multiplication is associative:
$$
(a\circ b)\circ c = ((ab)c)^\# = (a(bc))^\# = a\circ(b\circ c).
$$
But you can also prove it by brute force: expand
$$
(a\circ b)\circ c = \frac{(a\circ b)+c}{1+(a\circ b)c} = \frac{\frac{a+b}{1+ab}+c}{1+\frac{a+b}{1+ab}c} = \frac{a+b+c+abc}{1 + ab+ac+bc}
$$
and do the same with
$$
a\circ(b\circ c)
$$
and see if you get the same thing both ways.

$$
(\,\underbrace{x\circ x \circ x \circ\cdots\circ x}_{22\text{ terms}}\,)=0 \text{ if and only if } (\,\underbrace{x^\#\cdots x^\#}_{22\text{ factors}} \,)^\# = 0
$$
so you need $$(x^\#)^{22}=0^\# = 1.$$

Where you write $G=(-1,1)$ you must have intended $x,y\in G=(-1,1)$, and if that's what you meant, I think you should have said so explicitly.

I'm guessing that by "stabile part" you mean "stable part" and that means $G=(-1,1)$ is closed under this operation.

Answer (score 1):

By induction we prove that $$\underbrace{x\circ x \circ \cdots \circ x}_{n\text{ times}} =xh_n(x)$$ for some positive valued function $h_n$.
The statement is true for $n=2$ since $\frac{2}{1+x^2} >0.$ For $n+1$ we have $$\underbrace{x\circ x \circ \cdots \circ x}_{n+1-times } = x\circ (x h_n(x)) =\frac{x + xh_n(x) }{1 + x^2 h_(x) } =x \frac{1 +h_n (x)}{1 +x^2 h_n (x) } =xh_{n+1} (x).$$
So the assertion is proved.
Now if $n>1$ we obtain that $$\underbrace{x\circ x \circ \cdots \circ x}_{n\text{ times}} =0$$ if and only if $x=0.$